# Resume Video in MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am able to play the video files using the MPMoviePlayerViewController, Everything works fine. But if I press the Home Button, and open the application now, the video is removed from the super view. I know how to get the Notifications. Can you tell me how to resume the same video ?

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"adv" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL*  url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[_moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
```

I am playing the video using the above code. If I press the Home Button , and come back to the application , the video is gone. I am able to see only Loading..

Answer (score 5):

You should be able restart playback by calling `[_moviePlayer play]` when the application becomes active again.

You could either call back from the AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` method, or do something like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
  [_moviePlayer play];
}];
```

to add an observer for the notification (don't forget to remove it later).

Answer (score 0):

register for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification notification and check the endPlaybackTime value on _moviePlayer.moviePlayer property

then set the initialPlaybackTime to the previous end value next time the player is shown

Comment: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification is getting called whene the application is launched. When I press the home button and open the application again, it is not getting called